# Allow content with HTML tags for textarea custom fields in Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I have one small problem that dont know how to resolve myself.  I have this working function:

```
// Custom Field Product
function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

 global $woocommerce, $post;

  echo '<div class="options_group">';

 // Textarea
woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( 
array( 
    'id'          => '_textarea', 
    'label'       => __( 'Text Before Add to Cart:', 'woocommerce' ), 
    'placeholder' => '', 
    'description' => __( 'Enter the before add to cart button text here.', 
'woocommerce' ) 
)
);
woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( 
array( 
    'id'          => '_textarea1', 
    'label'       => __( 'Text After Add to Cart:', 'woocommerce' ), 
    'placeholder' => '', 
    'description' => __( 'Enter the after add to cart button text here.', 
'woocommerce' ) 
)
);

 echo '</div>';

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 
'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );

// Starting Save text
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){

// Textarea
$woocommerce_textarea = $_POST['_textarea'];
if( !empty( $woocommerce_textarea ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_textarea', esc_html( $woocommerce_textarea 
) );  

    // Textarea2
$woocommerce_textarea = $_POST['_textarea1'];
if( !empty( $woocommerce_textarea ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_textarea1', esc_html( 
 $woocommerce_textarea ) );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 
'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );

// Print content to product

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 
'add_content_after_addtocart_button_func' );

function add_content_after_addtocart_button_func() {

// Echo content.

echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_textarea', true );

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 
'add_content_after_addtocart_button_func1' );

function add_content_after_addtocart_button_func1() {

// Echo content.

echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_textarea1', true );

 }
```

But when insert text like this:

```
<b>random text. bla bla</b>
```

into field , and save, all the text is lost, and nothing is shown in product ? So my question is... How to use valid HTML tags like bold, italic, color etc into custom field? Why all the text is lost after save the text with HTML tags?

***EDIT*** : When replace this function:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_textarea1', esc_html($woocommerce_textarea ));
```

with this:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_textarea1', esc_textarea( $woocommerce_textarea ) );
```

print: `<b>blabla</b>`

but still nto formating tags as should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use instead [dedicated **`wp_kses_post()`** function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_post/), that will *"sanitize content for allowed HTML tags for post content"*.

So in your related hooked function code:

```
// Save custom fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){

// Textarea 1
if( ! empty( $_POST['_textarea'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_textarea', wp_kses_post( $_POST['_textarea'] ) );

// Textarea 2
if( ! empty( $_POST['_textarea1'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_textarea1', wp_kses_post( $_POST['_textarea1'] ) );
}
```

*This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).* Tested and works.